# Move items equally from each other/centre/angles?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I would like to move three copies, or an array of three copies, of a wall section away from each other equally, at 120 degree angles for a hexagon from the centre. Either way will help, or different items also, for more help. Thanks.

Basically just move 3 items away from each other at the same time. Like scale, but move instead. Can it be done using an array and scaling the array somehow, if the objects are at correct angles.  Will the array follow the normals or is it not possible?

picture-link.

[image: pic]

Comment: maybe show a picture of what you want (before/after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another option for less items, to just select one item, press <kbd>G</kbd>  to grab, then axis direction, press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> again for normals path travel, then press a value of use, such as 0.1, or -0.1, for each item

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then use push pull in the transform menu, as it will work once items are off centre.

Answer (score 3):

I think <kbd>Object</kbd>\<kbd>Transform</kbd>\<kbd>Push/Pull</kbd> is what you are looking for.
Select all objects in Object Mode and use <kbd>Object</kbd>\<kbd>Transform</kbd>\<kbd>Push/Pull</kbd> from the menu. As the name suggests it will push or pull from the center of all objects.

Based on your comment I assume what you are really looking for is an circular array. Here's a good tutorial for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLGYsd4lEjY
Once you set it up you can move your object in edit mode (so the origin stays at the same position) to push/pull the array from the center.

Comment: Can an array be used for this in some way or the normals by selection order or something else, because this does not work if the objects are at centre? Or another way to move objects by the angles etc?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in Blender 2.8 is to use scale tool to scale the location but not the size of objects. With the scale tool you can easily lock movement to any single axis or single plane. However, when using Push/Pull, if you lock movement to a certain axis it will split your objects into "groups" instead of moving them equally away from each other along that axis.

**STEPS:**

In Object mode, go to the top right of the 3D view and click on “options”

Then select to affect only the “locations”. Use the Scale tool and press "Shift Z" to lock the scaling to the Z-plane.

[image]

You can either scale from median point or from cursor location.

Here is a GIF tutorial:
[image]

Comment: does not work as the items are in the same axis and need an offset for it to work.

Comment: @dave44 It works, I just updated my answer with a GIF video tutorial. You need to make sure your pivot is set to Median Point

Comment: you are still using an offset, it does not work any different than if I manually move them then use push pull.  My image shows what I want to do from 3 objects in the SAME position, but rotated to follow normals.  Thanks for trying, but your gif shows they are separated at the beginning.